# Deeper Understanding of God's manner of redressing man's sinfulness (Isaiah 10:5-19) ( God uses Assyrians to discipline Israel & Judah )

Tags: isaiah, attributes-of-god, narrative-analysis

Isaiah 10:5-19 seems to characterize God’s complex/intricate & improvisational manner of how to redress man’s sinfulness by using “unlikely tools”(earthen vessels) at His disposal.

2 Corinthians 4:7 NASB 1995

> But we have this treasure in earthen vessels, so that the surpassing greatness of the power will be of God and not from ourselves;

Isaiah 10:5-8, 12, 13, 15-19 NASB 1995

> <sup>**5**</sup>  Woe to Assyria, the rod of My anger And the staff in whose hands is My indignation, <sup>**6**</sup>  I send it against a godless nation And commission it against the people of My fury To capture booty and to seize plunder, And to trample them down like mud in the streets. <sup>**7**</sup> Yet it does not so intend, Nor does it plan so in its heart, But rather it is its purpose to destroy And to cut off many nations. <sup>**8**</sup> For it says, “Are not my princes all kings?
> . . .
> <sup>**12**</sup> So it will be that when the Lord has completed all His work on Mount Zion and on Jerusalem, He will say, “I will punish the fruit of the arrogant heart of the king of Assyria and the pomp of his haughtiness.” <sup>**13**</sup> For he has said,  “By the power of my hand and by my wisdom I did this, For I have understanding; And I removed the boundaries of the peoples
> . . .
> <sup>**15**</sup>  Is the axe to boast itself over the one who chops with it? Is the saw to exalt itself over the one who wields it? . . . <sup>**16**</sup>  Therefore the Lord, the God of hosts, will send a wasting disease among his stout warriors; And under his glory a fire will be kindled like a burning flame. <sup>**17**</sup>  And the light of Israel will become a fire and his Holy One a flame, And it will burn and devour his thorns and his briars in a single day . . . <sup>**19**</sup>  And the rest of the trees of his forest will be so small in number That a child could write them down.

**Analogy of “a bleeding man walking in a forest using a dirty cloth stem said bleeding” to (Isaiah 10:5-19) God using Assyrians to discipline Israel & Judah**

[image: Composited clip art depicting a man in a forest with a wound and a dirty shirt on the ground]

1. A person who has a bleeding injury is walking alone in the jungle while he is profusely bleeding
2. Since there is no one around, and no first aid kit, the injured person knows that if he does not stem the bleeding ASAP then he might die
3. All of a sudden, the person sees a dirty and soiled piece of cloth lying on the ground in the forest
4. Using the dirty cloth to wrap around the bleeding injured area could cause serious infections/diseases for the person in the relatively distant future
5. However, the person knows that the two options are:

   a. High probability of facing death due to bleeding by just continuing to walk in the forest Unless he comes across some medical help soon

   b. Temporarily stem some of the bleeding at least by using the dirty cloth to wrap the injured area in question which would mean giving him some more time to seek medical help but also raises the chances of serious infections/diseases in the future which could also lead to death in the relatively distant future

Would the aforementioned analogy scenario be reasonably accurate when it comes to getting a deeper understanding of (Isaiah 10:5-19) God's use of Assyrians to discipline his Judah & Israel?

Comment: 'Redemption' I know of. 'Reconciliation' too. And 'justification'. But I have never read of 'redressing sin' in my bible.

Comment: redress means "remedy or set right". I don't see the problem.  Seem like another way of saying healing or restoring.

Comment: @user1338998 When I was in the Worldwide Church of God in the 70s and 80s Herbert W. Armstrong, the leader of the Church, wrote a book titled *The United States and British Commonwealth in Prophecy* in which he claimed Assryia was modern day Germany. He taught that Germany was going to lead a 10-nation United States of Europe and was going to defeat the USA and Britain in the third World War and carry them away into captivity. Then, he said, the kings of the East would attack the United Europe and that would end up in Jesus returning for the second time.

Comment: I am not joking. He really taught this. Some of the splinter groups of his Church still teach this to their members. I bought it hook, line, and sinker in the 70s and was expecting Germany to go to war against the United States in 1982. When 1982 passed I began to question some of the teachings of my Church and read about the history of the German people and the history of the Assyrian people. I came to the conclusion that I had been fooled and I left the Church in 1984.

Answer (score 1):

Analogies are rarely perfect, including this one. For one thing, the analogy seems to place Israel/Judah in the position both the infected person and the healer. But in the biblical account, Israel and Judah have become infected not by an accidental injury, but by violating God's commandment. The chosen nation has sinned. God chastises them in the hope that they will turn to him an be healed. Also, God faces no danger of being infected as does the person in the analogy. And yet it is God, not Israel/Judah, who uses the "dirty bandage" of Assyria.

Also Assyria is not a mere tool in God's hands but has its own portion of responsibility for its action, which is why it can be justly punished for its deed. If it were merely a tool, it would be unjust for God to chastise it. In speaking of Assyria both as his agent and as one who deserves to be punished, God speaks from a position outside of history. From a human viewpoint, it is a fact that Israel and Judah sinned, that God "used" Assyria to punish them, and God also punished Assyria for doing so. Humans try to understand this in various ways: to find analogies such as the OP has done, to affirm that Isaiah does not actually speak God's words but human ones, or to stand in awe of God's majesty and simply admit his ways are higher than our own.

Finally, to portray Assyria as "dirty" and the chosen people as clean is off the mark in my opinion. God has his purposes in choosing one nation over another but all nations and all people belong to God. A better analogy than Assyria being "dirty bandage" is Assyria being God's imperfect "servant," as was the case when God used Babylon (and later punished it) for a similar purpose.

> It is I who by my great power and my outstretched arm have made the
> earth, with the men and animals that are on the earth, and I give it
> to whomever it seems right to me. Now I have given all these lands
> into the hand of Nebuchadnez′zar, the king of Babylon, my servant, and
> I have given him also the beasts of the field to serve him. (Jer. 27:5-6)

---

Note: an example of the ambiguous attitude of the Bible toward nations such as Babylon (and Assyria) can be seen by comparing Jeremiah's positive characterization of the king of Babylon above with the Psalmist's imprecation:

> O daughter of Babylon, you devastated one,
> How blessed will be the one who repays you
> With the recompense with which you have repaid us.
> How blessed will be the one who seizes and dashes your little ones
> Against the rock. (Ps. 137:8-9)